# Reveal info by clicking on link

Tags: arrays, post, hyperlink, get

I have 4 links:

```
<a href=""><img src="img/photo1.jpg" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="img/photo2.jpg" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="img/photo3.jpg" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="img/photo4.jpg" /></a>
```

I also have md array:

```
$users = [
        "id_1" => [
                    "personal_id" => "111111",
                    "name" => "Arthur Novickov",
                    "location" => "Moskow",
                    "age" => "22",
                    "status" => "online"
                    ],
        "id_2" => [
                    "personal_id" => "222222",
                    "name" => "Zack Snyder",
                    "location" => "New York",
                    "age" => "21",
                    "status" => "offline"
                    ],
        "id_3" => [
                    "personal_id" => "333333",
                    "name" => "Anthony Briggs",
                    "location" => "Louisiana",
                    "age" => "36",
                    "status" => "offline"
                    ],
        "id_4" => [
                    "personal_id" => "444444",
                    "name" => "Anne Telma Louise",
                    "location" => "London",
                    "age" => "19",
                    "status" => "online"
                    ],
            ];
```

After all, I need to reveal info about user, when clicking one of those links. But (!) I don't know, how to let the script know, which one has been clicked. 
I thought, may be to prepare this info in advance with visibility: none and then set an event on click. But that sounds stupid, because there can be 50 links.

Here's the code for info revealing, if smth:

```
function show_info($person) {
                switch ($person) {
                    case '1':
                        echo $users["id_1"]["personal_id"];
                        echo $users["id_1"]["name"];
                        echo $users["id_1"]["location"];
                        echo $users["id_1"]["age"];
                        echo $users["id_1"]["status"];
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        echo $users["id_2"]["personal_id"];
                        echo $users["id_2"]["name"];
                        echo $users["id_2"]["location"];
                        echo $users["id_2"]["age"];
                        echo $users["id_2"]["status"];
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        echo $users["id_3"]["personal_id"];
                        echo $users["id_3"]["name"];
                        echo $users["id_3"]["location"];
                        echo $users["id_3"]["age"];
                        echo $users["id_3"]["status"];
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        echo $users["id_4"]["personal_id"];
                        echo $users["id_4"]["name"];
                        echo $users["id_4"]["location"];
                        echo $users["id_4"]["age"];
                        echo $users["id_4"]["status"];
                        break;              
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can include a data tag in your link: `<a href="..." data-personId="1">...</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to use links to pages coded in PHP.

In that case, adding the script name in the href attribute and including a querystring parameter will pass the information.

```
<a href="page.php?person=4"><img src="img/photo4.jpg" /></a>

<?php

if (isset($_GET['person'])) {
    show_info($_GET['person']);
} 

function show_info($person) {
    global $users;
    if (isset($users['id_'.$person])) {
        $user = $users['id_'.$person];
        echo $user["personal_id"];
        echo $user["name"];
        echo $user["location"];
        echo $user["age"];
        echo $user["status"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, User2182349, that worked fine for me, thank You!